# showing an asp:ModalPopupExtender using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am trying to show an asp:ModalPopupExtender using jQuery, without any success. Here is what I have :

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender BehaviorID="confirmPopup" ID="confirmPopup" runat="server" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function ShowConfirmPopup() {
    var _id = '#<%= confirmPopup.ClientID %>';
    var modal = $find(_id);
    modal.show();
}
```

What happens is that `modal` is always equal to `null`, so the popup never gets shown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[$find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397441.aspx) is not part of jQuery, but of [ASP.NET AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx). Therefore, you should not prefix the behavior id with a hash sign:

```
function ShowConfirmPopup()
{
    var modal = $find("confirmPopup");
    modal.show();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but still, even without the hash sign, it doesn't find the control

Comment: @JFB, that's probably because the `ClientID` of your control is not the same as its behavior id in your case. Since you explicitly specify a behavior id in your markup, it also makes sense to hard-code it in the client-side code. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: édéric, OK! Since I am using MasterPages, the `ClientID` gets altered, so it's better to use `BehaviorID` like this: `var _id = '<%= confirmPopup.BehaviorID %>';`